# Are dotted/dashed colored vectors possible in matplotlib quiver?

Tags: matplotlib

I am working on a project and we decided to use matplotlib.
For a polar chart we have a bunch of colored vectors which need to be recognizable from each other.

Now I have been able to get this:
[image: polar chart]

Quiver add is simply:

```
Q.append(sub.quiver(0,y_min_max[0], real_coords[i], imag_coords[i], color=color, scale=y_min_max[1]*2, zorder=5)
```

But is it possible to have dashed colored vectors?

The closest answer I found is this one [Plotting dashed 2D vectors with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352129/plotting-dashed-2d-vectors-with-matplotlib)

Which is close but I've only managed to get colored vectors surrounded with dashed lines instead of dashed vectors

[image: Dashed vector]

```
Q.append(sub.quiver(0,y_min_max[0], real_coords[i], imag_coords[i], color=color, scale=y_min_max[1]*2, zorder=5, linewidth=0.5,  linestyle = '--'))
```

I've been experimenting with various combinations but no luck for now, any ideas?
Thanks in advance